# How do I save SFTP settings for all new projects?

Tags: templates, phpstorm, settings, jetbrains-ide

I have a PHP project where I already have the SFTP settings configured under deployment. However, whenever I make a new project, the deployment section is blank and I have to reconfigure it again each time. Is there a way to save these settings so I don't have to keep reconfiguring it with each new project I create?

Answer (score 0):

In the deployment configuration, uncheck the `Visible only for this project` checkbox.

[image]